# Importing typed functions

Tags: julia

I can't seem to import a function with typed arguments. Luckily, I have a minimal failing example.

Given a `Query` defined in `structs.jl`:

```
module Structs

export Query

struct Query
    name::String
    data::Int
end

end
```

And a simple function `dist` which uses this type:

```
module Utils

include("structs.jl")
using .Structs: Query

export dist

function dist(x::Query, y::Query)
    return (x.data - y.data) ^ 2
end

end
```

Why can `dist` not be found, when I call it in `import_test.jl`?

```
include("structs.jl")
using .Structs: Query

include("utils.jl")
using .Utils: dist

a = Query("a", 1)
b = Query("b", -1)

println(dist(a, b))
```

Instead, it fails with the error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching dist(::Query, ::Query)
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
 [2] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1041
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [5] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:229
 [6] _start() at .\client.jl:421
in expression starting at C:\Users\mr_bo\julia_test\import_test.jl:13
```

However, if I remove the types from the `dist` function, such that it becomes `function dist(x, y)`, the error no longer occurs.

Am I import the `Query` type/struct incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you define module `Query` twice and those are two distinct modules. Then `Query` from one module is not the same as `Query` from the other module.

You can define what you want like this (I am giving an example without `include` statements, but you could introduce them to get the same effect):

```
module Structs

export Query

struct Query
    name::String
    data::Int
end

end

module Utils

using ..Structs: Query

export dist

function dist(x::Query, y::Query)
    return (x.data - y.data) ^ 2
end

end

using .Structs: Query
using .Utils: dist

a = Query("a", 1)
b = Query("b", -1)
println(dist(a, b))
```

Now you might say that you want `structs.jl` and `utils.jl` files to live independently. Then you should make a package out of `structs.jl` and then you can load it in `utils.jl` inside a module as well as in `import_test.jl` in outer scope and Julia will know that `Query` is the same definition. The steps to achieve this are described [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Pkg/) in the Julia manual.